# Unable to Call Jquery function using razor code

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have jquery function which I need to call using razor code. 
Below is my jquery function:

```
(function ($) {
        fixheader= function () {
            $('td:nth-child(' + column + '),th:nth-child( ' + column + ')').width("5px");
            $("#GridHeader").html("<table>" + $('#HtmlGrid table thead').html() + "</table>");
            $("#GridHeader table tr:first").append("<th></th>");
            $("#GridBody").html("<table>" + $('#HtmlGrid table tbody').html() + "</table>");

            $("#HtmlGrid").hide();

        };
    })(jQuery);
```

Below is my call from razor code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                    fixheader();
                </script>
```

I am not able to call jquery using this code. Error :  fixheader is not defined

Answer (score 0):

You are defining `fixheader()` inside the `document.ready` initialization so its scope stays there. Thus, you can't access it outside the `document.ready` block.

Edit: Moving it outside

```
(function ($) {

})(jQuery);
```

is one way of fixing your problem.

Comment: I tried this but not working. Still the same not defined error.

Answer (score 0):

You can call function from same `$(function(){...});` block as shown below

```
(function ($) {
   fixheader= function () {
     $('td:nth-child(' + column + '),th:nth-child( ' + column + ')').width("5px");
     $("#GridHeader").html("<table>" + $('#HtmlGrid table thead').html() + "</table>");
     $("#GridHeader table tr:first").append("<th></th>");
     $("#GridBody").html("<table>" + $('#HtmlGrid table tbody').html() + "</table>");

     $("#HtmlGrid").hide();

    };

    //call function here
    fixheader();
})(jQuery);
```

OR Define function in javascript way as shown below

```
<script>
function fixheader(){
   $('td:nth-child(' + column + '),th:nth-child( ' + column + ')').width("5px");
   $("#GridHeader").html("<table>" + $('#HtmlGrid table thead').html() + "</table>");
   $("#GridHeader table tr:first").append("<th></th>");
   $("#GridBody").html("<table>" + $('#HtmlGrid table tbody').html() + "</table>");

   $("#HtmlGrid").hide();

}
</script>
```

Comment: can you post a jsfiddle link with your problem statement, so that I can help you better.

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: fixheader is not defined VM3848:2(anonymous function) VM3848:2(anonymous function) jquery-1.7.2.js:614jQuery.extend.globalEval jquery-1.7.2.js:615(anonymous function) jquery-1.7.2.js:6078jQuery.extend.each jquery-1.7.2.js:660jQuery.fn.extend.domManip jquery-1.7.2.js:6068jQuery.fn.extend.append jquery-1.7.2.js:5845(anonymous function) jquery-1.7.2.js:5963jQuery.extend.access jquery-1.7.2.js:855jQuery.fn.extend.html jquery-               1.7.2.js:1193done jquery-1.7.2.js:7538callback

Comment: It is very difficult to figure out the exact error, I only can say that `fixheader` function is looking out of scope for the area from where you are calling it.